# When I click a link in Google Chrome the Thunderbird Account Wizard opens

Tags: google-chrome, email, thunderbird

On a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation every time I click a link in *Google Chrome*, the *Thunderbird Account Wizard* opens instead of sending me to the new window.

[image]

Comment: What kind of links are you clicking? Perhaps email ids (mailto:someone@example.com)? Then it's an expected behaviour.

Comment: After you verify that you don't click on e-mail links, could you please try if the same issue occurs with other web browsers, e. g. Firefox?

Comment: I am clicking the Order Now! The same happens if I use firefox !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Looks like I had to send an email. That's why the account wizard was opening. To set up the email system on this computer. Thanks for your answers.